# Ошибка "Выражение имеет константное значение"

Tags: c, массивы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Выбивает ошибки при объявлении масивов: N - должно быть константное, хотя  объявляю его константным. Почему ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
double f(double x)
{
    return sin(x);
}
void progonka(double* y, double* h, const int N, double* c)
{
    int i = 1;


    double alfa[N + 1], beta[N + 1], hamma[N + 1], delta[N + 1], A[N + 1], B[N + 1];
    alfa[1] = hamma[1] = delta[1] = 0.0;
    beta[1] = 1.0;
    for (i = 2; i <= N; i++)
    {
        alfa[i] = h[i - 1];
        beta[i] = 2 * (h[i - 1] + h[i]);
        hamma[i] = h[i];
        delta[i] = 3 * (((y[i] - y[i - 1]) / h[i]) - ((y[i - 1] - y[i - 2]) / h[i - 1]));
    }
    hamma[N] = 0.0;
    A[1] = -hamma[1] / beta[1];
    B[1] = delta[1] / beta[1];
    for (i = 2; i <= N - 1; i++)
    {
        A[i] = -hamma[i] / (alfa[i] * A[i - 1] + beta[i]);
        B[i] = (delta[i] - alfa[i] * B[i - 1]) / (alfa[i] * A[i - 1] + beta[i]);
    }
    c[N] = (delta[N] - alfa[N] * B[N - 1]) / (alfa[N] * A[N - 1] + beta[N]);
    for (i = N; i > 1; i--)
    {
        c[i - 1] = A[i - 1] * c[i] + B[i - 1];
    }
}
```

Comment: Если уж пишите на Си, то и компилируйте соответсвующим компилятором.

Comment: Используйте `#define N 42`, а не в параметр функции

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Константное в данном контексте означает - известное во время компиляции!

Ну не поддерживает Visual Studio (вы же им пользуетесь?) возможность VLA...

Или выделяйте массивы размера, достаточного при любом вашем N, либо выделяйте их динамически (только потом не забывайте удалять, освобождая память).

Comment: Объясни, пожалуйста, что такое возможность VLA. Какой редактор поддерживает это ?

Comment: Variable Length array - массив переменного размера. Когда размер становится известен во время выполнения, а не во время компиляции. Редактор? Написать можно в любом, хоть в Word'е или Notepad'е. Компилятор - например, gcc.

Comment: м, в ворде? поподробнее с этого момента. хочу увидеть как doc/docx будет компилироваться:)

Comment: Никто не мешает сохранить в формате txt ))

Comment: @KoVadim Вам уже ответили :)

Comment: да, главное const не забыть написать